# Can't install HAXM with Hyper-V disabled, AMD processor

Tags: android-emulator, virtualization, haxm

When I try to install HAXM I get the error:

```
This computer does not support Intel Virtualization Technology (VT-x) or it is being exclusively used by Hyper-V. HAXM cannot be installed. Please ensure Hyper-V is disabled in Windows Features, or refer to the Intel HAXM documentation for more information.
```

But in Windows Features Hyper-V is disabled: [hyper-v disabled in features](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EwAhF.png)

In my system info, I have "Hyper-V - Virtualization Enabled in Firmware" as "No"; does has something to do with the problem?: [hyper-v system info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N6kgR.png)

My processor is an AMD, can I even have HAXM in and AMD pc?

If not, what can I do to run an Android emulator? (With Android Studio).

Comment: AMD CPUs don’t support Intel VT-x (they have different hardware support for virtualization) and that message implies that HAXM hasn’t been enabled to work on AMD CPUs.

Comment: So how can I use Android Studio's Android Emulator without it? @prl

Answer (score 1):

https://developer.android.com/studio/

Requirements and recommendations
The Android Emulator has additional requirements beyond the basic system requirements for Android Studio, which are described below:

SDK Tools 26.1.1 or higher
64-bit processor
Windows: CPU with UG (unrestricted guest) support
HAXM 6.2.1 or later (HAXM 7.2.0 or later recommended)
The use of hardware acceleration has additional requirements on Windows and Linux:

Intel processor on Windows or Linux: Intel processor with support for Intel VT-x, Intel EM64T (Intel 64), and Execute Disable (XD) Bit functionality

AMD processor on Linux: AMD processor with support for AMD Virtualization (AMD-V) and Supplemental Streaming SIMD Extensions 3 (SSSE3)

AMD processor on Windows: Android Studio 3.2 or higher and Windows 10 April 2018 release or higher for Windows Hypervisor Platform (WHPX) functionality

To work with Android 8.1 (API level 27) and higher system images, an attached webcam must have the capability to capture 720p frames.